# Use Vuejs to use one tab for control and another for displaying

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to create an App with vuejs for displaying photos and I would like seperate the view container from the control of the photos via a new tab or a new instance of the browser. How should I start with something like this? Should I use two nodejs server and implement a rest API for communication? Or it is possible to use a vue router with several route and modify the components in these routes?

I only need a point to start.

Thank you in advance.

Michael

Comment: you can go with two rest api using node.js

Comment: Yes, but isn't there a better way for this problem?

Comment: or write code in same component open control on new window

Comment: You want to control in one tab which image is displayed in the other? If it's in the same browser, you could use localStorage and [`storage` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) or [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

Comment: Do you have a minimal example for this?

Comment: @wilkoklak That sounds like a solution. Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: Just read the documentation for BroadcastChannel. You could create an instance in each component, with the same name (you pass it as an argument in constructor).
You handle controlling in one component - when user clicks an image, you call `postMessage('path_to_image')` and the other component will listen for that message with `bc.onmessage = (path_to_image) => viewImage(path_to_image)`

Comment: @wilkoklak Thank you, this idea is good. But I prefer to solve this problems with vuejs own tools. But this will be a good fallback implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think found a solution. A shared vuex store should solve my problem. A good example could be found here:

https://vuejsexamples.com/share-and-synchronize-status-between-multiple-tabs-with-this-plugin-for-vuex/

Comment: Just so you're aware, the library you mentioned just uses localStorage and the `storage` event like @wilkoklak already mentioned.
As always, remember to weigh the pros and cons of just grabbing a library vs. writing the functionality yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In fact this is true but unfortunately I do not have got that time. Therefore I am searching for a out of the box solution.